# Grub-install options for specific partitions

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, grub

I've been trying to use grub bootloader to load arch on my machine. I've asked a similar question previously and wasn't able to configure the setup to my liking. Right now I have a hard drive with arch and windows 10 installed that is partitioned like this:

```
nvme0n1
-nvme0n1p1
-nvme0n1p2
-nvme0n1p3
-nvme0n1p4
-nvme0n1p5 /boot
-nvme0n1p6 SWAP
-nvme0n1p7 /
-nvme0n1p8 /home
```

Where p1-4 are windows partitions. I want to dual boot archlinux and windows.

I have previously tried installing grub using the command:
`grub-install target=i386-pc /dev/nvme0n1`
After I make the config and try to boot into arch, I fail at the grubloader, it doesn't detect the boot partition.

What should I do from here? Is there a grub option to specify where the boot/swap/home partitions are?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Systems since 2012 with pre-installed Windows are UEFI. And then you need the UEFI version of grub installed. It will actaully install to the ESP - efi system partition, but you still install to a drive. With separate /boot you have to mount both / & /boot when installing grub. Or use Boot-Repair in correct boot mode. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: It is a BIOS system